# OSX Bundle Architecture

Tags: objective-c, macos, architecture, bundle

I need to compare the architecture of a bundle and compare it to the machines architecture from an installer; if they match the installation will proceed else it will abort.
Getting the architecture is easy by using macros; I would like to know if there is a way of checking the architecture of the bundle to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will determine if the current application (or whatever bundle determined to be the `mainBundle`) shares a common architecture with the target bundle. Requires Mac OS X 10.5 for NSBundle's [`executableArchitectures`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-SW32) method.

```
NSArray *targetArch = p[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/path/to/bundle.bundle"] executableArchitectures];
NSArray *thisArch = [[NSBundle mainBundle] executableArchitectures];

if ([targetArch firstObjectInCommonWithArray:thisArch])
{
    // target bundle has architecture which matches current application
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the shell, you can do

```
otool -hv <path to mach-o image>
```

Images are usually in `Contents/MacOS` in applications or `Versions/Current` in frameworks